# How to insert commas into a file to make it a CSV?

Tags: csv, awk, sed, command-line-interface

I've just done some data capture into a CSV file but the commas are missing. Down to the nature of the data it looks to be a pretty straightforward job to add them back in using the right tools.

I have a feeling that `awk`, `sed`, `cut`, or similar could be useful but I'm not entirely sure how best to apply them.

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
17-03-07 20:45:56.400-1.0040.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.5003.1040.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.6002612.0039.50
17-03-07 20:45:56.7002611.0839.00
```

And here's how it should look:

```
17-03-07 20:45:56.400,-1.00,40.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.500,3.10,40.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.600,2612.00,39.50
17-03-07 20:45:56.700,2611.08,39.00
```

The rules of engagement are simple:

- There are three columns
- Add a comma after character 21 (after the 3rd decimal place of seconds)
- Add a comma 5 characters before the end of each line (only the middle column is of variable length

But how best to automate for 1,000s of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `sed` stream editor with specific regex pattern:

```
sed -Ei 's/^(.{21})(.+)(.{6})$/\1,\2,\3/' testfile
```

*Options:*

`-E` option, allows extended regular expressions

`-i` option, allows modifying(performing replacements) the file *in place*

---

*Regexp pattern constituents:*

`(.{21})` - the first capturing group for the first 21 characters

`(.+)` - the second capturing group for the *middle column of variable length*

`(.{6})` - the third capturing group for the last column of 5 characters

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '  {a[1]=0; a[2]=21; a[3]=length($0)-5;
        for(i=1;i<length(a);i++) printf "%s,",substr($0,a[i]+1,a[i+1]-a[i]);
        printf "%s\n",substr($0,a[i]+1)}' file
```

can be extended to more breakpoints, by adding points to array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/00/,"00,")sub(/.{5}$/,",&")}1' file

17-03-07 20:45:56.400,-1.00,40.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.500,3.10,40.00
17-03-07 20:45:56.600,2612.00,39.50
17-03-07 20:45:56.700,2611.08,39.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter:

```
length as $l
| [ .[0:21], .[21:$l-5], .[$l-5:] ]
| join(",")
```

and invoking jq with the `-Rr` options (raw input, raw output), produces the desired results.